# size of button on navigation bar Xcode9.4

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, xcode9-beta

i was working on Xcode 8.2 and everything was fine in my interfaces
but when i update my Xcode to Xcode9.4 and i open the main.storyBoard and all the buttons in the navigation bar sizes is change and it is extremely increase

**Screenshot Xcode**

[image]

i try to change the width but it does not allow me to change the number of the width
i have no idea about what is happen

what i can do to change the size

thanks

Comment: Xcode 9.4 is still in beta...could be be a bug that gets fixed before Xcode 9.4 is released. For production work, you should really be using Xcode 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the changes in iOS 11, either you have to take image of correct pixels( for ex: 32x32) or you must set constraints to the bar button items.

**1. You must set constraint to bar button**

Suppose you have taken outlet of your back button as:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var backBarButton: UIButton!
```

In `viewDidLoad`, Set:

```
    backBarButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    backBarButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
```

**2. Take image of pixel size 32x32**

Use back button with pixel size of 32X32, as navigation button takes the content size of image.

[image]